# Check if the data exists in snowflake table (python)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to check if the data exists in a snowflake table

'''

```
conn = sf.connect(user=snow_username, password=snow_password, account=snow_account, 
wharehouse=snow_wharehouse)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "Use Database testDatabase"
cur.execute(query)
video_id = "5XDBVX9cAAw"
channel_name = "test_channel"
query = (f""" SELECT video_id FROM {channel_name}  WHERE video_id = {video_id};""")
cur.execute(query)
cur.fetchone()
```

'''
but I get the following error, I am not sure what's wrong as I am able insert data into the table.

ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 47 unexpected 'XDBVX9cAAw'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the query:

```
query = (f""" SELECT video_id FROM {channel_name}  WHERE video_id = {video_id};""")
```

Which is using string interpolation(SQL Injection possible), after subsitution the query is resolved as:

```
SELECT video_id FROM test_channel WHERE video_id = 5XDBVX9cAAw
                                                   -- this is not string literal

-- should rather be
SELECT video_id FROM test_channel WHERE video_id = '5XDBVX9cAAw'
```

A cleanear approach is to use parameter binding:

```
query = (f""" SELECT video_id FROM TABLE(?)  WHERE video_id = ?;""")
cur.execute(query, (channel_name, video_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that by using `if` statement.

Also, your query string is not correct as you haven't added a string inside where condition value part i.e `{video_id}` ->`"{video_id}"`

The correct query is `query = (f""" SELECT video_id FROM {channel_name}  WHERE video_id = "{video_id}";""")`

```
conn = sf.connect(user=snow_username, password=snow_password, account=snow_account, 
wharehouse=snow_wharehouse)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "Use Database testDatabase"
cur.execute(query)
video_id = "5XDBVX9cAAw"
channel_name = "test_channel"
query = (f""" SELECT video_id FROM {channel_name}  WHERE video_id = "{video_id}";""")
cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchone()


if data != None:
   print(f"Record exists for video_id : {video_id}\n {data}")
else:
   print(f"Records not exist for video_id : {video_id}")
```

Comment: : Add a try catch to your code. Just incase any error it will be catched